# How can I reduce the amount of items displayed on the screen?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a issue: when I click on the DropdownButton, it shows a long list of items to choose from, but I don't know how to reduce the amount of items shown.

I add the code I created for the list and for the DropdownButton

[image]

```
List _months = [
    "01",
    "02",
    "03",
    "04",
    "05",
    "06",
    "07",
    "08",
    "09",
    "10",
    "11",
    "12",
  ];

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    txt = TextEditingController();
    _dropDownMenuItems = getDropDownMenuItems();
  }
    List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> _dropDownMenuItems;
      String _currentMonth;


      List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> getDropDownMenuItems() {
        List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> items = List();
        for (String month in _months) {
          items.add(DropdownMenuItem(
            value: month,
            child: Text(
              month,
            ),
          ));
        }
        return items;
      }

DropdownButton(style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                        iconEnabledColor: Colors.white,
                        value: _currentMonth,
                        items: _dropDownMenuItems,
                        onChanged: changedDropDownItem)
```

Can someone help me? Thanks